# Using Countdown to initialise a method before the time hits 0

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app that counts down to 0 but when there's 5 seconds left, it plays a sound file each second until it hits 0.

I know the code to initialize a countdown is...

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }
     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

But I can't figure out how to actually use this to initialize a separate method once the time remaining is either equal to or less than a specific value.

Comment: can't you place the sound playing code/method inside the `onTick` method in an `if` statement, where the `if` statement will check if the `millisUntilFinished` variable has the required values e.g. `5000`, `4000` etc?

Comment: Can you change your interval value to 1 instead of 1000 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private final int EXPIRY_TIME_IN_MILLI = 1 * 60 * 1000;
private final int TIME_INTERVAL_IN_MILLI = 1000;

private void setCountDownTimer() {
    final int milliSeconds = EXPIRY_TIME_IN_MILLI + TIME_INTERVAL_IN_MILLI;
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milliSeconds, TIME_INTERVAL_IN_MILLI) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (millisUntilFinished < milliSeconds / 2) {
                binding.delayText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            binding.countDown.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.count_down), String.format("%02d", minutes), String.format("%02d", seconds)));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            binding.countDown.setText("00:00");
        }
    };
    countDownTimer.start();
}
```

Above code worked for me